# Assertion failed. trying to create an image using Magick++

Tags: c++, debian, imagemagick, semaphore, magick++

I am trying to run this simple code from this [example](https://imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf) on page 8. I am trying to create an image and then write it but it won't even let me create the image.

This is the code:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Magick::Image p("300x300", "red");
    //~ p.write("red.png");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the compilation command:

```
g++ Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs main.cpp -o main
```

Here is the error:

```
main: magick/semaphore.c:606: LockSemaphoreInfo: Assertion `semaphore_info != (SemaphoreInfo *) NULL' failed.
Aborted
```

I am using Debian 9 on Virtualbox. It compiles perfectly fine. It just doesn't run and I don't know what that error means. I also can't find it online. Can someone please help?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but  you seem to be missing some back-ticks in the compilation command. Please copy-paste relevant code and commands as-is, without modifications. And please do copy-paste, don't try to rewrite inside the question, as it will in almost all cases add unrelated errors.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried copy-paste the full error message into your favorite search engine and see what you find there? Chances are someone else will already have had the same problem mas you, and posted about it, possibly with solutions (from the poster or from others).

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't initialized magick because I thought that was only for windows users. Here is the updated code.

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick(nullptr); // <--- added this line
    Magick::Image p("300x300", "red");
    p.write("red.png");
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else facing this issue.